# Set C# callback on a C++ struct obtained via P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop, dllimport

I am trying to use an external C++ dll I have been given (I don't have the source).

The DLL has a single function that returns a pointer to a `struct`.
That `struct` defines a series of function pointers to be used as callbacks by my application.

According to the "documentation" I received, I just "register" my callbacks by setting the pointer to my own callback method, like this:

```
server->OnConnectionRequest = &myObj.OnConnectionRequest;
```

However, I am trying to achieve this in C#.
I have partially succeeded. I can:

- load the DLL;
- obtain the `struct*` pointer from the function;
- call some methods that are predefined on the object.

What I can't do is setting my own callbacks on the object: the compiler does not complain, the runtime does not complain, but the callbacks are still not called.

I defined the delegate type and the class as such (note that previously this was defined as a struct, and it didn't work just the same):

```
// Original C++ signature from the header:
// void (*OnRemoteConnectionRequest)(void *caller, const char *ip, int &accept);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void OnRemoteConnectionRequestDelegate(IntPtr caller, string ip, ref int accept);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class RemoteServerPluginI
{
    public OnRemoteConnectionRequestDelegate OnRemoteConnectionRequest;
    // another dozen callbacks omitted
}
```

I have a static helper to retrieve the instance from the dll:

```
public static class RemoteControlPlugin
{

    [DllImport("data/remoteplugin.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetServerPluginInterface();

    private static RemoteServerPluginI _instance = null;

    public static RemoteServerPluginI Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance != null)
                return _instance;

            var ptr = GetServerPluginInterface();
            _instance = Marshal.PtrToStructure<RemoteServerPluginI>(ptr);
            if (_instance == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not obtain the server instance");

            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the way I am using to register my callbacks:

```
public class CallBacks
{
    public CallBacks(RemoteServerPluginI server)
    {
        server.OnRemoteConnectionRequest = this.OnRemoteConnectionRequest;
    }

    public void OnRemoteConnectionRequest(IntPtr caller, string ip, ref int accept)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Remote connection request from {ip}");

        // I try to force a reject to see an error on the client,
        // but the client always connects successfully, implying
        // we never get to run this
        accept = 0;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var cb = new Callbacks(RemoteControlPlugin.Instance);
    RemoteControlPlugin.Instance.StartServer();
}
```

And yet, when I use the client application to try to connect to my server my callback is never run. As you see, in my callback I'm refusing the connection, therefore the client should exit with an error, but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The data flow is wrong, you have to tell the native code about *your* callback functions.  So Marshal.StructureToPtr().  Be sure to save your copy of the struct in a static variable its delegate objects won't be garbage-collected.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but I'm not sure we are on the same page. The struct has already been allocated by the C++ dll, and I'm supposed to set the callbacks on the instance *they* created. Unless I misunderstood your answer completely?

Comment: You are not "allocating" a struct, you are updating it.  We can't see enough to guess if you also need to use Marshal.PtrToStructure() to preserve existing fields in the struct that you don't want to modify.  You won't if it only contains function pointers.

Comment: Well, the code in the C++ dll has found some memory for a struct and it's giving me the pointer. The structure only contains function pointers: some of them have already been assigned by the dll and point to code that I will need to call, others are null when I retrieve the pointer and I need to assign my callbacks to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one:

```
_instance = Marshal.PtrToStructure<RemoteServerPluginI>(ptr);
```

will create a copy of `RemoteServerPluginI`, so you'll work on the copy. Clearly wrong.

Use `Marshal.WriteIntPtr()` to write directly to `ptr`, like:

```
Marshal.WriteIntPtr(remoteServerPluginIPtr, 0, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(OnRemoteConnectionRequest));
```

Where instead of `0` you should put the offset of the delegate pointer in the `struct`.

Then you aren't showing us the C signature of the callback... Perhaps you made some errors even there.

As written by Voigt, the other **very** important thing is that the delegate must be kept alive for all the time that the native library can use it. The standard way to do it is to put it in a field/property of an object and then be sure to keep alive the object (for example keeping a reference to it). You are doing this with the `class RemoteServerPluginI`. Another way to do it is to `GCHandle.Alloc(yourdelegate, GCHandleType.Normal)` and then `GCHandle.Free()` when you are sure the native code won't call it ever.

Some simple example code.

C side:

```
extern "C"
{
    typedef struct _RemoteServerPluginI
    {
        void(*OnRemoteConnectionRequest)(void *caller, wchar_t *ip, int *accept);
        void(*StartServer)(void);
    } RemoteServerPluginI;

    void StartServer();

    RemoteServerPluginI _callbacks = { NULL, StartServer };

    void StartServer()
    {
        int accept = 0;
        _callbacks.OnRemoteConnectionRequest(NULL, L"127.0.0.1", &accept);
        wprintf(L"Accept: %d", accept);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) RemoteServerPluginI* GetServerPluginInterface()
    {
        return &_callbacks;
    }
}
```

C# side:

```
[DllImport("CPlusPlusSide.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr GetServerPluginInterface();

public static void RemoteConnectionRequestTest(IntPtr caller, string ip, ref int accept)
{
    Console.WriteLine("C#: ip = {0}", ip);
    accept = 1;
}

public class Callbacks
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void OnRemoteConnectionRequestDelegate(IntPtr caller, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string ip, ref int accept);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void StartServerDelegate();

    public OnRemoteConnectionRequestDelegate RemoteConnectionRequest { get; set; }

    public StartServerDelegate StartServer { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
IntPtr rsp = GetServerPluginInterface();

var callbacks = new Callbacks
{
    RemoteConnectionRequest = RemoteConnectionRequestTest
};

Marshal.WriteIntPtr(rsp, 0, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callbacks.RemoteConnectionRequest));
callbacks.StartServer = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<Callbacks.StartServerDelegate>(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(rsp, IntPtr.Size));

callbacks.StartServer();
```

Note that, by your example, `StartServer` is a delegate contained in the `RemoteServerPluginI` C struct. So we have to retrieve its value with `Marshal.ReadIntPtr` and create a .NET delegate for it. Note the use of `GC.KeepAlive()` to be sure an object is kept alive until a certain point in the code. Other common method is using a `static` variable (the lifetime of `static` variables is until the end of the program)

Example with incapsulation of the various `Marshal`:

```
public class Callbacks
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void OnRemoteConnectionRequestDelegate(IntPtr caller, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string ip, ref int accept);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void StartServerDelegate();

    private IntPtr ptr;

    public static implicit operator Callbacks(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        return new Callbacks(ptr);
    }

    public Callbacks(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        this.ptr = ptr;

        {
            IntPtr del = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr, 0);

            if (del != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                remoteConnectionRequest = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<OnRemoteConnectionRequestDelegate>(del);
            }
        }

        {
            IntPtr del = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr, IntPtr.Size);

            if (del != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                startServer = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<StartServerDelegate>(del);
            }
        }
    }

    private OnRemoteConnectionRequestDelegate remoteConnectionRequest;

    private StartServerDelegate startServer;

    public OnRemoteConnectionRequestDelegate RemoteConnectionRequest
    {
        get => remoteConnectionRequest;
        set
        {
            if (value != remoteConnectionRequest)
            {
                remoteConnectionRequest = value;
                Marshal.WriteIntPtr(ptr, 0, remoteConnectionRequest != null ? Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(remoteConnectionRequest) : IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
    }

    public StartServerDelegate StartServer
    {
        get => startServer;
        set
        {
            if (value != startServer)
            {
                startServer = value;
                Marshal.WriteIntPtr(ptr, IntPtr.Size, startServer != null ? Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(startServer) : IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
Callbacks callbacks = GetServerPluginInterface();
callbacks.RemoteConnectionRequest = RemoteConnectionRequestTest;
callbacks.StartServer();

while (true)
{
}
```

Note that then I would make everything strongly type, totally hiding the `IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport("CPlusPlusSide.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern CallbacksPtr GetServerPluginInterface();

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CallbacksPtr
{
    public IntPtr Ptr;
}

public class Callbacks
{
    public static implicit operator Callbacks(CallbacksPtr ptr)
    {
        return new Callbacks(ptr.Ptr);
    }

    private Callbacks(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        ...
}
```

Adding a `CallbacksPtr` that is a shim for the `IntPtr` that can be implicitly converted to a full `Callbacks` object.

Comment: I was just going to comment on the copy and the failure to convert delegate to function pointer -- you explained them both.  One more important thing to note is that when using `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`, something has to keep the delegate instance alive, since when it becomes unreachable, the trampoline will be freed along with it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was going to add it... But it has a `RemoteServerPluginI` class that acts as a container for the delegate, so he is on the right road.

Comment: He won't have one after removing the harmful copy (`PtrToStructure` call)

Comment: @BenVoigt The same thing that I thought :cry:

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to modify it immediately. I've also updated the question to include the original signature from the C++ header.

Comment: > Use Marshal.WriteIntPtr() to write directly to ptr, like:

That's clear but not exactly straightforward. I assume there's no way to "cast" directly the pointer to an instance of my class without copying, right? That would be very convenient :(

Comment: @MicheleIppolito: Changing the return type of `GetServerPluginInterface` might work, but your class isn't compatible with the C struct so it wouldn't be nearly as helpful as you think.  (A field of delegate type is not the same as the function pointer with the same signature as the delegate -- both are pointers, but the delegate is a pointer to a data object, not directly to code)  You can't avoid the `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` call.

Comment: @MicheleIppolito You can incapsulate it a little... But the code becomes overlong...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, both of you :)
The solution with WriteIntPtr was still not working, so I dropped down to C++/CLI where it was easier to work with pointers. Once there I was able to find a second unrelated problem with my usage of the dll, and now it's working!